# Inserting "bigger" data into PostgreSQL makes the system faster?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, varchar

So, I witnessed the following behaviour while using PostgreSQL.

I have a table like this: `(id INTEGER ..., msg VARCHAR(2000))`
and then I run two programs `A` and `B` that do the exact same thing,
namely doing 20000 insertions and then 20000 retrievals (based on their id). The only 
difference is that program `A` does insertions with messages containing
2000 characters while `B` just inserts messages containing at most 10 characters.

The thing is that the average time of all the insertions and retrievals
in `A` is always about ~15ms less than in `B` which doesn't really make sense,
since `A` is adding "bigger" data.

Any ideas or hints on why this could be happening? Could it be that when not using
all the characters of the `msg` the system uses the rest of the space for other purposes and therefore if `msg` is full the system is faster?

Based on @Dan Bracuk comment. I save the time on different events and realized that the following happens, in program `A` there quite a few times that insertions are really really fast while in program `B` this is never the case and that's why on average `A` is faster than `B` but I cannot explain this behaviour either.

Comment: Put timer events in each program to see where the difference comes from.

Comment: @DanBracuk changed my question based on your comment. Thanks!

Comment: VARCHAR and TEXT do not pad the empty characters if the full length is not used (CHAR does that). Does removing the "(2000)" length restriction (VARCHAR(2000) becomes simply VARCHAR) change the results at all? Is this on a totally quiescent system? Are the averages over several runs consistent?

Comment: @bma Actually the same happens when I change from `varchar(2000)` to `varchar`. The system is pretty quiescent I guess and I have done several runs and it was always the same different, `>= 10ms`.

Comment: You're saying that A uses bigger chunks of data and takes longer, right?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry :S, no I meant `A` takes a shorter amount of time (fixed my questions).

Comment: How are you inserting? Are you loading the data via COPY statements?

Comment: AFAIK there is a size threshold where PostgreSQL will separate large columns from the main table on disk, that could have interesting effects on the seeking behavior, records per disk block, etc. I'm more of an app guy than a DBA guy so I don't know enough about the low levels guts to say any more.

Comment: The out-of-line storage is called TOAST (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html), and it might very well be the case here, if the data being inserted exceeds 2kB.

Comment: Do you get consistent results when you run `A` then `B` vs `B` then `A`?  What are your indices?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades, actually yes, I runned first A and then B and vice versa and had the same results. What do you mean by indices?

Comment: AKA "indexes".  Clustered, non-clustered, unique, synthetic, primary, foreign.

Comment: Just a guess: Cache (WAL buffers)? Maybe small values are added to a write cache and only committed when the cache fills up. Larger data fills the cache so it is written immediately but small data wait and the timing data reflects that? How are you getting your timing data anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this without more detail about your setup and your programs, so the following is just an educated guess.  It's conceivable that your observation is due to TOAST.  Once a text field exceeds a certain size, it is stored in a physically separate table.  Therefore, the main table is actually smaller than in the case where all the text values are stored inline, and so searches could be faster.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for your answer. Perhaps it's TOAST but I want to be sure. So I tried inserting messages to see where "bigger" data has an impact on the observable time. From understanding I would see a difference if my tuples are about 2KB of size.  The thing is I don't know when my tuples go over 2KB in size, so I asked here how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928633/find-the-byte-size-of-a-row-in-postgresql (I guess it's a different question).

Comment: Ok, after my question there was answered and having checked it it doesn't make any sense, I have the increase long before my rows reach 2KB each (actually it's about at 500bytes). So when inserting rows of 500 bytes each or greater the system becomes faster in contrast to inserting elements of 50 bytes each let's say. This contrast is visible up to 200,000 bytes messages in which case the "bigger" messages are slower than the small ones. So I guess it doesn't have to do with TOAST. Right?