# Find the byte size of a row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, byte, varchar

Assuming I have a table in PostgreSQL, how can I find the exact byte size used by the system in order to save a specific row of my table?

For example, assume I have a table with a `VARCHAR(1000000)` field and some rows contain really big strings for this field while others really small. How can I check the byte size of a row in this case? (including the byte size even in the case [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) is being used).

Comment: Not sure you can get the TOAST size per row. Maybe try `bit_length` for TOASTable columns and add up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `pg_column_size` and `octet_length`.

See:

- [How can pg_column_size be smaller than octet_length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304572/how-can-pg-column-size-be-smaller-than-octet-length)
- [How can I find out how big a large TEXT field is in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983152/how-can-i-find-out-how-big-a-large-text-field-is-in-postgres/15983294#15983294)
- [How can pg_column_size be smaller than octet_length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304572/how-can-pg-column-size-be-smaller-than-octet-length/13304634#13304634)