# What is the size of a Django CharField in Postgres?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I was wondering what will be the size of the data let's say:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then the input is "John Doe"

What will be the size of the table row let's say?

```
-----------------
| id | name     |
-----------------
| 1  | John Doe |
-----------------
```

Comment: Use pg_column_size and octet_length.

Comment: can you clarify - you want the size of the postgresql row ? if yes, then the question title is making it look something totally different

Comment: @NabeelAhmed Thanks! and yes

Comment: Title of question saying you want to know CharField size in postgres. if yes then it all depends on max_length you defined, irrespective of whatever database you use.

Comment: So what's the storage size of above, considering that the max length is 255

Comment: this can be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928633/find-the-byte-size-of-a-row-in-postgresql

Comment: @NabeelAhmed, thanks!